# need to display other field on live status of other field

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user selects a state from a state drop-down, it will display a list of high-schools in a drop-down field.

I am able to display the high schools once the user selects a state, but I am having trouble when the user submits the form w/o selecting a high school. If they do not select a high school, it will not display the form.

That is not really the problem, that is one of the ways the form can fail validation, which brings me to my question.

When the user fails validation, it will display the same form with the fields filled in the info they inputted before submitting the form.

The state drop-down is pre selected with the state they selected, but the high school drop down is no where to be seen. If I unselect the state drop-down, then re-select a state, then the high school list will display.

I am using a bind change on the #state field.

How can I display the high school field w/o having to wait for a click or change on the state field?

```
<select name="state" id="state">
 <option></option>
 <option value="NY">NY</option>
 <option value="TX">TX</option>
</select>

<select name="high_school" id="high_school">
 <option></option>
 <option value="Bayside High">Bayside High</option>
 <option value="Ridgemont High">Ridgement High</option>
</select>

$("#high_school").hide();

$('#state').bind('change', function() {
  $("#high_school").show();
});
```

I assume I'll need to keep an eye on #state on load

Comment: please post your html, as well as jquery code...those two lines of code will not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are right, about keeping an eye on #state on load.

```
//check to see if something in #state is selected, if not hide #high_school
if($("#state").val() == '') {
    $("#high_school").hide();
}

$('#state').bind('change', function() {
  $("#high_school").show();
});
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/89K5G/

Try choosing #state, and refresh the frame :)